# Is it appropriate to link to "unofficial" web copies of commercial documents

Tags: discussion, copyright

I've not found this asked, so apologies if I've missed it...

Is it appropriate to link to web copies of commercial documents, where the publishing of that document is breaching copyright or licensing?

By way of example, in [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164359/how-come-verification-does-not-include-actual-testing) PeterK has linked to [a university copy of ISO12207](http://www.math.unipd.it/~tullio/IS-1/2009/Approfondimenti/ISO_12207-2008.pdf) (the document includes the statement `Single user license only, copying and networking prohibited`)

I appreciate that the WWW is a bit wild-west at times, but surely we should be upholding copyright and/or license restrictions in our Q&A?

Updated: naughty link in referenced post now deleted

Comment: Wait, why is a standard (especially an ISO standard) copyrighted?

Comment: Perhaps that's a question for another thread...?!  But (as commented below) having spent a lot of time over the past few years (and others have spent even more) working on the new MISRA guidelines, I have sympathy with both sides of the fence.

Comment: Opps, didn't even read those comments. The linked question explains it enough

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

We should respect the copyright of the original documents. This includes not copying and linking to the official sources rather than something "unofficial".

If nothing else the official link is likely to be more stable.

The documentation should also be **summarised** in the answer so that if the link does go dark we still have a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks... I assumed as much; and the referenced post has been updated also.

Comment: +1. It's [very annoying](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127534/why-do-programming-language-open-standards-cost-money) that some "open" standards are not freely available. But we have to obey the law. We might also choose to campaign for the standards to be made open.

Comment: Availability of standards is a tricky issue, I agree... but having spent a lot of time over the past few years working *pro bono* on the new MISRA C:2012 guidelines does give me the perspective from the other side, too